# How to get a button outside of a form to line up with button inside of form?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I feel like this is relatively simple styling, but i cant for the life of me figure out how to do it.

My code:

```
<div class="container py-5">
   <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right:5px">
      <form method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <p>
         <h3>
            Do you want to delete <em>"{{ entry.title }}"</em> posted on {{ entry.date_created|date:'Y-m-d' }}?
         </h3>
         </p>
         <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Confirm">Confirm</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   <a href="{% url 'entry-detail' entry.id %}">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
   </a>
</div>
```

I want both the Confirm and Cancel buttons to be aligned next to eachother, but if I put the Cancel besides the Confirm button or in a div inside of the form it too performs the delete action.

In Django using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your easiest solution is to put the cancel button in your form aswell, since your form is a block level element it wont let you put it next to it unless you change it to an inline level element. or make the parent a flexblox or grid container.

The solution:

```css
.button--container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<div class="container py-5">
   <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right:5px">
      <form method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <p>
         <h3>
            Do you want to delete <em>"{{ entry.title }}"</em> posted on {{ entry.date_created|date:'Y-m-d' }}?
         </h3>
         </p>
         <div class="button--container">
           <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Confirm">Confirm</button>
           <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'entry-detail' entry.id %}">Cancel</a>
         </div>

      </form>
   </div>

</div>
```

You will also notice I have changed your markup from `<a><button /></a>` to `<a></a>`. This is because you are not allowed to put an anchor tag inside a button or a button inside an anchor.

Comment: Thank you, this did it!! I did basically this before, but when clicking the Cancel button it performed the Confirm action for some reason. Maybe it was because of the messed up anchor tags.

Comment: I'm running into this problem when putting a second button inside a form element.